# Magento : How Magento Load Billing Information in Admin Order View Page and New Order EMail?

Tags: magento

I would like to rewrite the Magento Billing information section in admin order view page
and sales order email template.

I have customized some additional fields to stored in magento quote address and order address tables while checkout process is completed.

So i would like to show the stored data's in admin order view page and sales order email as well.

Any Help Much Appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the address template formats from the backend:`System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Address Templates`.
You have a field for each address format.
Each field has a placeholder in the address format between double curly brackets (`{{...}}`).
Let's say you want to add the field `street_number` to the html format of the address. Change it to this:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}} 

{{depend street_number}}Number: {{var street_number}}<br />{{/depend}}

{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

I've left a blank line above and below the line I added.

Comment: I have added the my custom field name in above admin panel, nothing to show. my custom field name "{{var collection_date}}". i have stored my additional info in sales_flat_order_address table.